# Rename document using rename view Document Browser-Based App

Tags: iphone, swift, uidocumentbrowservc

Rather than implementing my own document rename method, I would like to use the document browser default view that can be reached by clicking the title of a file in a document browser. To do this I believe that one must call the rename method referenced [here](https://developer.apple.com/documentation/appkit/nsdocument/1515231-rename). However, this method is for NSDocument and does not work on the iPhone. Is there a similar method for UIDocument or another way to do this altogether?